# Stop rectangle height size

Tags: .net, report, ssrs-2008

i have a dynamic table inside a rectangle, but this growup and push all the objets bellow to the bottom. i need stop this. anyone can helpme?

I try put the rectangle inside an textbox.

Comment: Have you set the `CanGrow` property to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent a rectangle from resizing itself to a larger size, you can set the `CanGrow` property to false.

Alternatively, you can set the `CanShrink` property to false if you want the rectangle to not resize itself any smaller.

[More info on these properties here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/ssrs/ssrs-properties-cangrow-and-canshrink/)